# Creating a view in SQL with a case statement in the select

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, view, syntax

I know something must be wrong with my syntax but I can't seem to figure it out.

I want to populate this column `prop_and_cas_dtl_prdct_desc` from either `expir_prop_and_cas_dtl_prdct_cd` or `ren_prop_and_cas_dtl_prdct_cd` depending on the value in `type_indicator` but before it goes into `prop_and_cas_dtl_prdct_desc` it should look up the `prop_and_cas_dtl_prdct_desc` from `pc_ref_detail_product_cd` and select the one corresponding to its `expir_prop_and_cas_dtl_prdct_cd` or `ren_prop_and_cas_dtl_prdct_cd`.

I apologize for the terrible indenting, I know it is difficult to read but this is the best way I know how to put it.

```
select
,ren_prop_and_cas_dtl_prdct_cd
...
,p_and_c_cd
,case when type_indicator in ('R','C') then 
    select prop_and_cas_dtl_prdct_desc
from  pc_ref_detail_product_cd a inner join op_pif_coverage_rpc_new b
on a.prop_and_cas_dtl_prdct_cd = b.expir_prop_and_cas_dtl_prdct_cd

else when type_indicator in ('N','O') then 
    select prop_and_cas_dtl_prdct_desc 
from pc_ref_detail_product_cd  a inner join op_pif_coverage_rpc_new b
on a.prop_and_cas_dtl_prdct_cd = b.ren_prop_and_cas_dtl_prdct_cd

else NULL
 END
AS prop_and_cas_dtl_prdct_desc
FROM         dbo.op_pif_coverage_rpc_new
```

Here is the code I used to create my reference table

```
create table pc_ref_detail_product_cd(
prop_and_cas_dtl_prdct_cd char(2),
prop_and_cas_dtl_prdct_desc  char(30)
)

insert into pc_ref_detail_product_cd (prop_and_cas_dtl_prdct_cd,     prop_and_cas_dtl_prdct_desc) 
values ('01', 'CORE'),
('02', 'FORECLOSED'),
('04', 'TRUST'),
('06', 'MORTGAGE HOLDERS E&O'),
('07', 'SECURITY INTEREST E&O')
```

Comment: The [sqlbeautifier](http://www.dpriver.com/pp/sqlformat.htm) could be helpfull with the indentation - but your statement contains errors and the beautifier gave up.

Comment: `CASE` in T-SQL is **only** an expression - it can **return** a single value for each `WHEN` clause. It is **NOT** however a flow control statement that allows for code execution (as in other languages)

Comment: Thanks for that sqlbeautifier link, that is really cool!

Answer (score 2):

If you need to select column from different table depending on value in additional column you need to include all tables in query, with appropriate `JOIN` and than use case statement like so

```
SELECT CASE WHEN a.MyColumn = 0 THEN b.SomeColumn
            WHEN a.MyColumn = 1 THEN a.SomeColumn
       END AS SomeColumn
    FROM MyTableA AS a
    JOIN MyTableB AS b
        ON a.ID = b.ID
```

Instead of select statement in case statement, you just going to select column from ether table that you need for each particular case.

Answer (score 0):

I got it figured out. Here is the SQL I used. Sorry if it wasn't apparent what I wanted to do from my horrible code in the original question.

```
select
,ren_prop_and_cas_dtl_prdct_cd
...
,p_and_c_cd
,case when type_indicator in ('R','C') then 
(select prop_and_cas_dtl_prdct_desc
from  pc_ref_detail_product_cd a where expir_prop_and_cas_dtl_prdct_cd = prop_and_cas_dtl_prdct_cd)

when type_indicator in ('N','O') then 
(select prop_and_cas_dtl_prdct_desc 
prop_and_cas_dtl_prdct_desc
from  pc_ref_detail_product_cd a where ren_prop_and_cas_dtl_prdct_cd = prop_and_cas_dtl_prdct_cd)

else NULL
END
AS prop_and_cas_dtl_prdct_desc
FROM         dbo.op_pif_coverage_rpc_new
```